# PostgreSql query plan projectset node

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I ran into a query plan containing a "projectset" subplan node which threw me off because there was no additional information with which to correlate it to the actual SQL clause. Here is the query and the plan. This is only an illustrative version of the original query.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT details FROM entitlements WHERE
(COALESCE(ARRAY_LENGTH('{foo,bar,baaz,alpha,beta}'::text[], 1), 0) = 0 
 OR details->>'application_id' IN (SELECT (UNNEST ('{foo,bar,baaz,alpha,beta}'::text[]))));
```

```
 Seq Scan on entitlements  (cost=0.05..2594.18 rows=2838 width=160) (actual time=24.234..24.236 rows=0 loops=1)
   Filter: (hashed SubPlan 1)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 5679
   SubPlan 1
     ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=5 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=5 loops=1)
           ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.054 ms
 Execution Time: 24.257 ms
```

**Questions**

- What is a "ProjectSet" node? I didn't find any documentation on it.
- Why doesn't it have additional info like values 'foo', 'bar' etc that we find in other nodes?

It is obvious here what it refers to but that wasn't true at all with the original much bigger query.

Comment: Do you seem more details when using `explain (analyze, verbose)`?

Comment: Yes, it does provide a little more information, perhaps sufficient to correlate with the SQL clause:


`Seq Scan on public.entitlements  (cost=0.05..2594.18 rows=2838 width=160) (actual time=33.603..33.604 rows=0 loops=1)
   Output: entitlements.details
   Filter: (hashed SubPlan 1)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 5679
   SubPlan 1
     ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=5 width=32) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=5 loops=1)`
           **Output: unnest('{foo,bar,baaz,alpha,beta}'::text[])**
           `-> Result (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1`